# Why does Spring Authorization Server use client_id as audience in an access token

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

Within org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.token.JwtGenerator#generate

The claims are built as:

```
claimsBuilder
    .subject(context.getPrincipal().getName())                 
    .audience(Collections.singletonList(registeredClient.getClientId()))                
    .issuedAt(issuedAt)
    .expiresAt(expiresAt);
```

But my understanding is that the audience of the access token should be the intended recipient, the API / resource server.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Try using use the resource server identifier like this `.audience(Collections.singletonList(resourceServerIdentifier))`

Comment: @Raky - that isnt my code - its a class within spring auth server.

Comment: Have you tried [customizing the token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer)? See the related [how-to guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/guides/how-to-custom-claims-authorities.html).